# How can we calculate the time until expected API response is received?

Tags: jmeter

Using Jmeter, I have the bellow scenario:

Make a POST Request to an API - This request make a deployment request and takes ~1 second to get a response that request has been made

Make a GET Request to an API - This request check if the deployment is completed. The response looks like {"Completed": true}

I need to calculate how long it takes from sending the POST response to the GET response returning true (trigger until it says true)

Is there a way to do it in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your GET request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and use [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function to check the "Completed" status variable value
2. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to the GET request to extract the status into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Put everything under [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure the cumulative time